# XSD/XSLT- map information to categories

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform information of persons to different categories. The basic idea is this:
Source:

```
<Person>
  <id1>1234</id1>
  <id2>4321</id2>
  <name>Doe</name>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <firstletter>J</firstletter>
  <sex>M</sex>
</Person>
```

Desired result:

```
<Result>
  <Categories>
    <Category>
      <name>ids</name>
      <number>01</number>
      <SubCategories>
        <SubCategory>
          <name>id1</name>
          <number>01</number>
          <value>1234</value>
        </SubCategory>
        <SubCategory>
          <name>id2</name>
          <number>02</number>
          <value>4321</value>
        </SubCategory>
      </SubCategories>
    </Category>
    <Category>
      <name>info</name>
      <number>02</number>
      <SubCategories>
        <SubCategory>
          <name>lastname</name>
          <number>01</number>
          <value>Doe</value>
        </SubCategory>
        <SubCategory>
          <name>firstname</name>
          <number>02</number>
          <value>John</value>
        </SubCategory>
        <SubCategory>
          <name>gender</name>
          <number>03</number>
          <value>M</value>
        </SubCategory>
      </SubCategories>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
</Result>
```

So the target contains repeating nodes, but the source doesn't. I want to map the elements within Person (not all of them) to the right categories.
I know which element belongs in which category and subcategory (as shown in the Desired result), but I don't know how to conditionally fill the Result.

Comment: "*I know which element belongs in which category and subcategory,*" But we don't, and this makes it difficult to understand your question.

Comment: There's a category and subcategory number for every type of information. The example shows which type of information belongs where. For example Person/sex belongs in Category 02 SubCategory 03. My question is how to conditionally map each child node of Person to the subCategory as shown in the Desired result.

Comment: I am afraid it's still too vague. Do you want to go over the list of categories and fill it out with the data from the source XML?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time michael.hor257k
To answer your question: Yes. The 'value' node will contain the value of the corresponding child node from the Source. The name of the subcategory is not necessarily the same as the name of the child node e.g. the value of Person/name (Doe) is mapped to the value child node of the subCategory with name 'lastname'. My question is: how would you transform the above source so you get the desired result shown? There probably isn't a very elegant solution, as you'll probably have to use hardcoded conditions, but I just can't get it to do what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here. Perhaps you just want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Person">
    <Result>
        <Categories>
            <Category>
                <name>ids</name>
                <number>01</number>
                <SubCategories>
                    <SubCategory>
                        <name>id1</name>
                        <number>01</number>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="id1"/>
                        </value>
                    </SubCategory>
                    <SubCategory>
                        <name>id2</name>
                        <number>02</number>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="id2"/>
                        </value>
                    </SubCategory>
                </SubCategories>
            </Category>
            <Category>
                <name>info</name>
                <number>02</number>
                <SubCategories>
                    <SubCategory>
                        <name>lastname</name>
                        <number>01</number>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </value>
                    </SubCategory>
                    <SubCategory>
                        <name>firstname</name>
                        <number>02</number>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
                        </value>
                    </SubCategory>
                    <SubCategory>
                        <name>gender</name>
                        <number>03</number>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sex"/>
                        </value>
                    </SubCategory>
                </SubCategories>
            </Category>
        </Categories>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to do the trick. I guess I wasn't expecting it to be this straightforward. I was thrown off by the errors given in design mode when defining multiple category nodes: "Repeating nodes not supported" as well as "<xsl:template match="/"> and <xsl:template name="..."> are the only permitted <template> elements in the XSL". But it still works when I test it.

Comment: @Lao Which tool is giving you these errors? -- Note that the above assumes there will be only one person in the input, with one value in each subcategory - as does your format.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the answer. The tool I used was jDeveloper 11, but sometimes its design mode is stricter than the source mode. It works either way :)